# Issue with installing CMAK - kafka manager

Tags: apache-kafka, sbt, yahoo-kafka-manager

I am trying CMAK on ubuntu 20.4 and I am following instruction on https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK and https://codeforgeek.com/setting-up-kafka-management-for-kafka-cluster/. After running command `./sbt clean dist` and trying to switch to directory `/target/` in am not seeing `universal` directory. Is there any thing I am missing?

Please see below screenshot.

After running: `./sbt clean dist`. I am getting below result.

```
 root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01-testing-server:/opt/CMAK-master# ./sbt clean dist
 [info] Loading settings for project cmak-master-build from plugins.sbt ...
 [info] Loading project definition from /opt/CMAK-master/project
 [info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
 [info] Set current project to cmak (in build file:/opt/CMAK-master/)
 [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Apr 4, 2021, 10:40:07 AM
 Warning: node.js detection failed, sbt will use the Rhino based 
 Trireme JavaScript engine instead to run JavaScript assets compilation, which in some cases may be orders of magnitude slower than using node.js.
 [info] Wrote /opt/CMAK-master/target/scala-2.12/cmak_2.12-3.0.0.5.pom
 [warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
 [info] Main Scala API documentation to /opt/CMAK-master/target/scala-2.12/api...
 [info] Compiling 136 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /opt/CMAK- 
 master/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
 model contains 640 documentable templates
 [info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
 [info] LESS compiling on 1 source(s)
 ./sbt: line 241:  7926 Killed                  "$@"
 root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01-testing-server:/opt/CMAK-master# 



 | => root / Web-assets / less 122s
 | => root / Compile / compileIncremental 352s
```

After that when navigating to `target` directory, there is no `universal` directory.

```
 root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01-testing-server:/opt/CMAK-master# ls
 LICENSE  README.md  app  build.sbt  conf  img  project  public  sbt  
 src  target  test
 root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01-testing-server:/opt/CMAK-master# cd target/
 root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01-testing-server:/opt/CMAK- 
 master/target# ls
 scala-2.12  streams  web / less 122s
 root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01-testing-server:/opt/CMAK-master/target# ls
 scala-2.12  streams  web
 root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01-testing-server:/opt/CMAK-master/target#
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you try looking in the target/scala folder? Besides, you're using Ubuntu, so create a Debian package, not a zip. `sbt debian:packageBin`

Comment: This did. Now univeral folder appears but there is no any zip file

Answer (score 0):

How to start Kafka-Manager?

1. download Scala https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html and install it.
2. clone yahoo CMAK git report in this location C:\Kafka_Manager\CMAK
3. here is sequence of command we must execute on Kafka manager location.

   - `sbt clean` :: clean directory
   - `sbt compile` :: compile directory
   - `sbt run` :: execute web application

   For stop execution

   - `netstat -ano | findstr :9000`
   - `taskkill /PID 3708 /F`
4. after successfully execute this command when you are visit localhost:9000
   below error trigger on cmd.

   - Cannot run program "node": Malformed argument has embedded quote;
     solution :: Add below line Program File(X86) > sbt > conf > sbtconfig
     -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
     Save IT.
   - Unable to canonicalize address kafka-manager-zookeeper:2181 because it's not resolvable
     solution :: C:\kafka_2.13-3.5.1\Kafka_Manager\CMAK\conf\application.conf
     Change text kafka-manager-zookeeper:2181 to localhost:2181 or you can use related
     zookeeper url.

Visit localhost:9000 and check your cluster and everything showing properly.